# What are the tools to draw icon for winform application?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, icons

I'm new to programming and to winform. I want to create an icon for my winform application. What are the common tools to create icon for winform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once I had worked in 3d animation field for few years. So I am pretty hands on with Adobe Photoshop and in general I use Photoshop to create icons for me. Its pretty simple and user friendly software for basic needs. Just create and export the icon in desired size. But its a paid software.
If you  wish to work on a free software, one can go for Gimp editor. But honestly i have never used it.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio you can add a new icon file. It will open an icon editor.
Then in the project properties you can select the icon file to use for your application.

Comment: will it support camera captured image?

Comment: @NewBie a camera captured image is unlikely to be a good icon

Answer (score 0):

You can take any raster image editing program that has the capability of exporting icon files and be done with it. Windows Forms is in no way different than any other application framework in that regard.

Visual Studio also provides an (albeit crude) icon editor.